# Know when a user views a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I know when a user is viewing a webpage like say they had 2-3 tabs open in their browser and then viewed your site. How could I know this?

If you look at this website: https://turbulenz.com/ you will see an example of it where whenever you re-visit the page after viewing another tab etc the page does some ajax and shows this with a little loading element in the top right.

Can anyone help? As this functionality is ideal for an application I am building that requires refreshing certain ajax calls when a user looks at the tab in their browser.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do:

At the server level track a user using a variety of schemes such as: async JavaScript beacon, session id on the server, or cookie

What you cannot do:

You cannot correlate a web session to a browser tab.  All active tabs in the browser share the same active server session and client-side identifiers.  You can test this on Amazon.  Search for a book in one tab and add it to your cart.  Search for a second different book in a second tab and add it to your cart.  In a third tab checkout and see what is in your cart.

Comment: That site clearly knows when you are and not viewing the tab though

Comment: I dont think the site knows when you aren't viewing it.  I think the window object has a `focus` event, so when it gets focus they can fire off ajax. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841179/detecting-tab-visibility-in-firefox

Comment: Agree with @dm05314 - The focus event is about as good as it'll get. Send off a message on initial load, and then start tracking focus. Just be aware that no system is perfect, so any metrics gathered are going to be ballparky.